# Where do reverse lookups get the value of the nameserver which holds the PTR records

Tags: dns, routes, bind, pointers, reverse-lookup

When I do a reverse lookup on my IP, it correctly finds one of our BIND nameservers and does a reverse lookup. How does it find our nameserver, where are the nameserver details stored? With RIPE/ARIN or on our Router (we have a class B block that points at our router) or with our WAN backbone provider?

I understand the whole process of forward lookup starting with root hints (. > .COM. > example.COM. > www.example.com.) and how the nameserver is found but am not sure of the process for IPs.

Thanks

Comment: your LDNS (or something it refers to) should have a reverse zone as well as a forward zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's exactly the same process for reverse lookups. The only thing that is somewhat special about reverse lookups is that the name being looked up is derived from an IP address.

Comment: OK, but where are the name server details recorded? We have a ton of IP addresses pointing at us. The nameserver is not set up on our router. Is it stored with RIPE? How does a server know to check with ns1.domain.com for 1.1.1.1 when 1.1.1.0 or 1.1.0.0 do not point at the nameserver

THe same way Nominet keep a record for the name server of "example" when someone looks up example.uk

Comment: In the delegation information for the zone, as usual. The zone in your example being `1.1.1.in-addr.arpa.`. There is no magic automatically tying together your IP addresses with the reverse domains. You need to talk to whoever has the domain above you in the reverse tree and ask them to delegate to you. That is almost certainly the same people who gave you the IP addresses in question.